# Query user data with angularfire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2, angular5

I'm working on a simple app, where I need to fetch the data from a specific user. Heres's the code I have in my service/provider

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth){
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(
        user => {
            this.notesCollection = this.afs.collection<Note>('notes', ref =>
                ref.orderBy('created', "desc")
                .where('trashed', '==', false)
                .where('user', '==', user.email));
        }
    );
}
fetchNotes(): Observable<NoteId[]> {
    this.notes = this.notesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions =>{
        return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Note;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return {id, ...data};
        })
    });
    return this.notes;
}
```

But, when I call the fetchNotes method from my page, I get an error basically saying that the `notes` variable is undefined. I know it's due to the user observable executing in the constructor, but, I don't know any other way to get the user info and making the queries, so, if you could help to find another way to do this, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of posting a link to a picture of your code, edit your question to include the actual code as text. Stack Overflow can take care of highlighting the code if you use the tools on the toolbar (or tag your question with the language that your code is written in).

Comment: i am not sure i got your problem. if you have the user email in your component page you can pass it to `fetchNotes(userEmail)`, than do it in the constructor

Comment: Yes, I could, but then I would have to execute the query everytime I want to fetch the notes, that wouldn't affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

I'd get this working like so:

```
notes: Observable<NoteId[]>;
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth){
    this.notes = this.afAuth.authState.switchMap(user => {
       if (user) {
           return this.afs.collection<Note>('notes', ref =>
                ref.orderBy('created', "desc")
                .where('trashed', '==', false)
                .where('user', '==', user.email)).snapshotChanges()
       } else {
          return of([]);
       }
    }).map(actions =>{
        return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Note;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return {id, ...data};
        })
    });
}
```

So the key concepts are A) embrace Observables (`fetchNotes()` could get you in trouble, if you need the current value for some reason use a BehaviorSubject) B) switchMap the authState C) map right on the assigns